# Replacing text in Microsoft word with wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, replacement

In Microsoft Word, I am trying to eliminate time stamps formatted as [00:33:11]. I used the
wildcard search [*] but this does not work. Can someone explain how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
2. In the Find what box, type:`\[[0-9]{2}:*\]`.
3. Click More, select "Use wildcards".
4. Press Find Next.